# Why Insert creates a transaction for itself? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, sql-insert

I execute this:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

INSERT INTO Foo (counter) values ((select @@TRANCOUNT))
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT

COMMIT
```

Insert should trigger a transaction start.

**Expected**: `1` is displayed and stored in the table.

**Actual**: `1` is displayed, but `2` is stored in the table.

Why SQL Server behaves like that - `INSERT` creates a transaction internally? It doesn't really bothers me, but I'm just curious is there anything I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer does not fulfill question. Inconsistent results where a transaction is left open sometimes. Left answer, but can be deleted if so desired/required.**

In theory, since a transaction has started by the execution of sp_prepexec, the insert shouldn't begin a new transaction. However, since this is using a system stored proc to execute dynamic SQL, I'm not sure the rule of joining transactions, while Implicit Transactions are off, applies. Changing when @@Trancount is obtained to outside the INSERT results in a value of 1 in both cases, leading to possible evidence there are actually two transactions underway in your original query.

```
set implicit_transactions on

Declare @P2 int;  

EXEC sp_prepexec @P2 output,   
    NULL,
    N'DECLARE @tc INT
      SET @tc = @@trancount
      insert into FOO (counter) values ((select @tc))
      select @@TRANCOUNT';   
EXEC sp_unprepare @P2;
```

Comment: Execution of a procedure doesn't start a transaction (and is not listed as such in MSDN). I checked your example, it's still 2 as well.

Comment: That isn't what I'm getting, I get 1 when I select * from foo.

Comment: Double checked it. It's 0 table value in my case (and 1 value on select, as before).

Comment: Turns out it's not `sp_prepexec` issue. I've just tried `insert` even without wrapping it in the `sp_prepexec` and it gives the same saved value 2.

Comment: I've checked your initial code and my redone code and I get inconsistent results. First time I get 0 and 1 (As you did), then I get 1 and 1. There's a "phantom?" transaction after running the first time. Edited answer.

Comment: Don't you forget to commit your transaction after the first time?